# SiteMap in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sitemap, mvcsitemapprovider

We are using siteMap controller in MVC 4. Our system has a tree with nodes representing various modules.
We would like to show the currently selected module in form of breadcrumb.

We have used siteMap controller and defined a code on _layout.cshtml page as follows

```
<body>
@Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu(false, true, true)
<p>Start of Breadcrumbs:</p>
@Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()
@RenderBody()
```

When we run the application, it neither shows the breadcrumb nor produces any error.

Please guide.

Thanks.

Comment: Its hard to say what the problem is without seeing more of your configuration. Did you define your nodes in Mvc.sitemap and add title, controller and action attributes?

Comment: Yes. Please find the code snippet as below

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mvcSiteMap xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0 MvcSiteMapSchema.xsd">

  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Service Provider" controller="ServiceProvider" action="Index" >
    
  </mvcSiteMapNode>

</mvcSiteMap>

Comment: It would be most helpful if you would make a small demo project and either upload it somewhere or post it on GitHub so I can take a look. There simply isn't enough information about your configuration in your question to give you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, I would say that you don't have enough XML to make a sitemap because there is only a single node defined. It also has to match your routes (or URLs) or the sitemap won't function. There is no error because there is no minimum number of nodes, but 1 isn't enough to produce a tree structure.

My suggestion is to read [Routing Basics](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Routing-Basics) so you understand how the route-to-node matching process works. Failing that, have a look at the [MvcMusicStore demo](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/tree/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcMusicStore) or one of the [demos I have created](https://github.com/NightOwl888?tab=repositories) to see an example of a working configuration.